# SICP 5.2 Assembler

Tags: scheme, sicp

I've been reading through chapter 5 of sicp and have gotten stuck on a piece of code--namely, the assembler presented in 5.2. This is what it looks like:

```
(define (extract-labels text receive)
    (if (null? text) 
        (receive '() '())
        (extract-labels (cdr text)
        (lambda (insts labels)
            (let ((next-inst (car text)))
                (if (symbol? next-inst)
                    (receive insts
                             (cons (make-label-entry next-inst insts)
                                   labels))
                     (receive (cons (make-instruction next-inst) insts)
                              lables)))))))
```

Isn't the lambda only going to be called when the text is null?  So how can we ask for the car of 'text' then?

*EDIT*

Thanks for the answers, but I'm still not seeing it.  If the text is not null, doesn't extract-lables call itself recursively, until the text is null?  In which case how can we call the car of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda gets the appropriate scope: at the time the lambda is defined `text` is not null, so calling `car text` works fine.

Answer (score -1):

`if` takes up to three arguments: a condition, a `if-true` (then) expression, and an `if-false` (else) expression. The indentation is all weird, so it looks wrong.

It should appear as

```
(define (extract-labels text receive)
    (if (null? text) 
        (receive '() '())
        (extract-labels (cdr text)
            (lambda (insts labels)
                (let ((next-inst (car text)))
                    (if (symbol? next-inst)
                        (receive insts
                                 (cons (make-label-entry next-inst insts)
                                       labels))
                        (receive (cons (make-instruction next-inst) insts)
                                  labels)))))))
```

Observe that the result of the expression is `(receive '() '())` if `text` is null and `(extract-labels ...)` otherwise.